# How to write a working URL to a Mifare Classic 1K

Tags: hex, nfc, mifare

Quite simply, I am only able to write to this card in hexadecimal. After much research, I can only find methods to write a working URL(that opens the browser on mobile), that use specific apps that are not compatible with the card I have. I would love it if one of you clever folks could explain to me the method by which I can turn a URL into the correct format, and where(sector, headers etc...) I should store it within my card. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Mifare Classic Tags are non standard, so there is no reliable way on all mobile hardware to write a URL that will automatically open a browser.

Most mobile hardware supports the NFC standard Tag's and some support reading from Mifare Classic Tags (but not all).

If reading from a non standard Mifare Classic Tag is supported then there is a chance that the NDEF data format will be also supported.

All mobiles will handle automatically URL's encoded in the NDEF format.

First you need to format the Mifare Classic Tag in a way to store NDEF, see the NXP application note https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1305.pdf on how to do this.

Once configured to store NDEF data you can store a URL using NDEF URI type - details at https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_URI_1.0.pdf

Writing the data in this way will cause a fair number of mobiles to open a URL in a browser without any App, but also a fair number won't even read the Mifare Tag.

Comment: Thanks for that, I forgot to mention that the card is UID rewritable, I didn't think that would make much of a difference, however, it seems I was wrong and that this functionality makes the method you said impossible, which is probably also the reason most NFC writer apps I tried did not work.

Comment: I would not think that having a rewritable UID, would affect the encoding of data in the memory pages, BUT usually a Mifare Tag which has a rewritable UID is a Chinese cloned chip not an authentic NXP one and this might affect the functionality in other ways.